# Detect strange pdf rendering

Tags: pdf, scanning, rendering

I used `simple-scan` to scan hundreds of documents. A few pdfs render strangely with `evince`:

[image]

Fortunately, using `LibreOffice` and exporting as pdf produces the desired pdf output (purposely compressed), also visible using `Firefox` to read the pdf:

[image]

All the methods I tried (`qdf`, `pdfinfo`, `jhove`) return that the pdf file is valid. How
can I detect all the "broken" pdfs? And of course, I'm interested in a more straightforward fix than manually exporting pdf from LibreOffice.

Comment: The PDF isn't corrupt, it's just fine. The fact it rendered at all means the PDF is OK. This isn't to say there isn't some way to detect this, but it won't be by checking the validity of the file.

Comment: @music2myear Indeed. Any clues on how to detect this?